# How to display Custom taxonomy on custom post listing page

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to show the custom taxonomy name on the listing of custom post type on my front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code in the custom post type listing template

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy_name' ,  ' ' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get terms by posts with this functions.

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "ids"));
```

And echo or use different with **foreach()**. This tip get terms with ID. You can get another properties. [wp_get_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) in codex.

1. Get term by id and taxonomy => $term = get_term($term_id, 'my_taxonomy');
2. Get term name by id => $term->name;
3. Get term link by id = >get_term_link($term_id, 'my_taxonomy'); // [codex for it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)